# Matching IDs in 2 different foreach loops in PHP (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

So basically, what I'm trying to achieve is calculating the tax percentage on each food category.

Lets suppose `category number 5` having the `tax percentage of 8%`.

So based on simple **formula** to calculate **tax** on each item is:

> **ITEM COST** * **TAX %** / **100** = **Tax Amount**

**So I have 2 arrays**

**ARRAY 1**:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [5] => 8    // [CATEGORY-ID] => TAX %
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [22] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [32] => 0
        )

)
```

**ARRAY 2**:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [5] => 4.6   // [CATEGORY-ID] => ITEM COST
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [5] => 10.33
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [22] => 1.15
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [32] => 4.59
        )

)
```

**table food-category**
[image: here]

Some sub functions used inside **get_per_tax_amount()**

```
/**
  * GET CATEGORIES-ID FROM ADDED CART ITEM OF THE USER
 */
public function get_category_id_from_cart_item()
    {
         $cart_items = $this->cart_model->get_all();

         $data = array();
         foreach ($cart_items as $cart_item) {
             
            $menu_details = $this->menu_model->get_cat_by_menu_id($cart_item['menu_id']);
            $data[] = $menu_details['category_id']; //array(1, 2, 2, 3);
         }

         return  array_unique($data); // Array is now unique (1, 2, 3)

    }

    /**
     * GET TAX % FROM CATEGORY-ID
     */
    public function get_category_tax_value()
    {
         
         $cat_ids = $this->get_category_id_from_cart_item();
         $data = array();
         foreach ($cat_ids as $cat_id) {
            $this->db->select('id,tax');
            $this->db->where('id', $cat_id);
            $category_data = $this->db->get($this->table)->row_array();
            $data[] =  array($category_data['id'] => $category_data['tax']); 
          }
       return $data;
    }

    /**
     * GET SMALLER DATA FOR CART PAGE : PER-MENU PRICE
     */
    public function get_per_menu_price()
    {
        $cart_details = $this->get_all();
        $data = array(); 
        foreach ($cart_details as $cart_detail) {
  
            $menu_details = $this->menu_model->get_cat_by_menu_id($cart_detail['menu_id']);
            $data[] = array($menu_details['category_id'] => $cart_detail['price']);               
            
        }
        return $data;
        
    }
```

Example:

```
public function get_per_tax_amount()
    {
         $percentages = $this->category_model->get_category_tax_value();  //array 1
         $units = $this->cart_model->get_per_menu_price(); //array 2
         $total_vat = array();
         foreach ($percentages as $cat => $proportion) {
            
            foreach ($units as $unit_cat => $price) {
                
                if($cat == $unit_cat){

                     $total_vat[] = (floatval($price) * floatval($proportion)) / 100;

                }else{

                     $total_vat[] = (floatval($price) * floatval($proportion)) / 100;
                }
            }
         }

         return $total_vat;
    }
```

**output is:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.01
    [1] => 0.01
    [2] => 0.01
    [3] => 0.01
    [4] => 0.01
    [5] => 0.01
    [6] => 0.01
    [7] => 0.01
    [8] => 0.01
    [9] => 0.01
    [10] => 0.01
    [11] => 0.01
)
```

I don't know why I am getting this output.

So my problem is, how do I match the **CATEGORY-ID** using foreach loop and get each item tax amount?

Comment: I think above all you'd need to explain how you handle duplicate entries (your second array has category 5 twice) and show what you've tried. This is a relatively straightforward task; loop one array, try to fetch same key from the other array, if it exists do something. If not, maybe do something, maybe nothing. Don't know, you haven't really presented a problem or a clear case.

Comment: I added a use-case please have a look.

Comment: The issue of multiple possible values still isn't resolved. The category id of 5 in the first array can be matched with two different elements from the second array (`4.6` and `10.33`). How do you decide which one should be picked? Or do both need to be applied?

Comment: I want it to both need to applied, thats the part where I am currently stuck!

Comment: Are you able to change the way your input arrays are structured? This task could be made much simpler if you had an optimized structure.

Comment: I just added few more sub function into the question maybe help to better understand.

Comment: One more thing - can the first array logically contain duplicate category ids?

Comment: Well, I deliberately make category-ID unique in array 1 because of fetching tax% in 
 each row from database using get_category_tax_value() but yes maybe its possible. but, keep in mind the returning data from this function is coming from database.

Comment: refresh the page I added table structure of category as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a relatively straightforward algorithm if you restructure your input arrays. Currently, you have ungrouped data and some unnecessary levels. This adds complexity to your function that is supposed to calculate tax amounts. If we redesign the arrays to a more fitting format, we can simplify the function.

The array that holds tax percentage values per category can be a simple one-dimensional array (because here you logically do not need duplicate values), like so:

```php
// [CATEGORY-ID] => TAX %
Array
(
    [5] => 8    
    [22] => 9
    [32] => 0
)
```

The one that holds item prices and their categories could be made into an array where top level keys are category ids and their values are subarrays of all item prices in that category, like so:

```php
// [CATEGORY-ID] => ITEM COST
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.6   
            [1] => 10.33
        )
    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.15
        )
    [32] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.59
        )
)
```

With arrays neatly organized, we can now reduce the calculation function to this:

```php
function get_per_tax_amount() {
    $percentages = $this->category_model->get_category_tax_value();
    $units = $this->cart_model->get_per_menu_price();
    $total_vat = [];
    foreach ($units as $unit_cat => $prices) {
        foreach ($prices as $price) {
            $total_vat[] = $price * $percentages[$unit_cat] / 100;
        }
    }

    return $total_vat;
}
```

How it works:

- We don't need to loop the percentage array at all. We will only use it for reference.
- The outer loop iterates over the units and the inner loop iterates over all the unit prices in the category.
- For every price, we simply access the index in the percentage array equal to the current category key of the outer loop and do the calculation. You might want to add a check if that array key exists in the percentage array (this code assumes it will exist) and then handle that case however would be best for your application (throw exception, return empty array...).

Now, I haven't tested this final bit, but to achieve these array structures, I believe you only need to change the following:

1. In the `get_category_tax_value()` function, change this:

```php
$data[] =  array($category_data['id'] => $category_data['tax']);
```

to this:

```php
$data[$category_data['id']] = $category_data['tax'];
```

to remove the extra dimension.

2. In the `get_per_menu_price()` function, change this:

```php
$data[] = array($menu_details['category_id'] => $cart_detail['price']);
```

to this:

```php
$data[$menu_details['category_id']][] = $cart_detail['price'];
```

to add prices in a subarray.

Comment: Thankyou....So much this approach is way better then mine..and its optimize and structured. thankyou for your help.